# Why LSTM doesn't predict low and high values in regression?

Tags: keras, regression, lstm, loss-function, activation-function

I made a stack of bidirectional LSTM layers following by 4 Dense/Dropout layers with a swish activation function in order to predict a continuous value between 0 and 2. I compiled the model with mean_squared_error loss function, Adam optimizer and with a batch size of 32.

The issue I encounter is that the extremities (low and high values) are not well predicted by the network, somehow the minimum predicted value is 0.16 and the maximum is 1.85. See image below (the point at (2,2) coordinates is not part of the LSTM prediction):

[image]

I would like to improve the prediction in the tails, *i.e* being able to get prediction lower than 0.16 and higher than 1.85.

Below is the network I built:

One input data is composed by 6 values representing displacements and distances.

```
num_features = 6

MODEL = Sequential()
MODEL.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(2**6, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1),
                        input_shape=(None, num_features), merge_mode='concat'))
MODEL.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(2**5, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1),
                        input_shape=(None, num_features), merge_mode='concat'))
MODEL.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(2**4, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.1),
                        input_shape=(None, num_features), merge_mode='concat'))

MODEL.add(Dense(2**5, activation='swish'))
MODEL.add(Dropout(0.2))
MODEL.add(Dense(2**4, activation='swish'))
MODEL.add(Dropout(0.2))
MODEL.add(Dense(2**3, activation='swish'))
MODEL.add(Dropout(0.1))
MODEL.add(Dense(2**2, activation='swish'))
MODEL.add(Dropout(0.1))
MODEL.add(Dense(1, activation='swish'))

MODEL.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['MAE', 'accuracy'])

CALLBACKS = [
    EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20, min_delta=1e-4, verbose=1),
    ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=4, min_lr=1e-9, verbose=1),
    ModelCheckpoint(filepath='stackLSTM_best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, verbose=1)
]

HISTORY = MODEL.fit(x=TRAIN_SET['feature'],
                    y=TRAIN_SET['label'],
                    epochs=1000,
                    callbacks=CALLBACKS,
                    batch_size=2**5,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_data=(VAL_SET['feature'], VAL_SET['label']),
                    verbose=2)
```

Does someone here got a similar problem? What could be the issue? I tried to min-max scaled the labels from 0 to 1 instead of 0-2 and I tried other activation functions (sigmoid, linenar) but it didn't help. May be there is a specific loss function or optimizer to use in this case?

Thanks for your help!

**Update:**
I removed the penultimate Dense layer and change the activation function to ELU, I obtained the extremity values however the global prediction is surprisingly less well than in the previous result:

```
MODEL = Sequential()
MODEL.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(2**6, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1),
                        input_shape=(None, num_features), merge_mode='concat'))
MODEL.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(2**5, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1),
                        input_shape=(None, num_features), merge_mode='concat'))
MODEL.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(2**4, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.1),
                        input_shape=(None, num_features), merge_mode='concat'))
MODEL.add(Dense(2**5, activation='elu'))
MODEL.add(Dropout(0.2))
MODEL.add(Dense(2**4, activation='elu'))
MODEL.add(Dropout(0.2))
MODEL.add(Dense(2**3, activation='elu'))
MODEL.add(Dropout(0.1))
# MODEL.add(Dense(2**2, activation='elu'))
# MODEL.add(Dropout(0.1))
MODEL.add(Dense(1, activation=None))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add the excerpt of the code corresponding to where the model is defined, compiled, and fitted? Also, share an excerpt of your dataset's input and output (if possible). If the dataset was generated by you, please provide the code for that too. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Chicodelarosa, I updated my post with the code and my last result.